# IPoint -> Nearest Address

Tags: arcgis-engine

**Summary: How to use the MDB file (link below) as a locator to reverse geocode (point->address) with ArcMap?**

I've implemented this sample:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_find_the_address_closest_to_a_point_using_reverse_geocoding/0001000001n9000000/

The sample works with a file ESRI provided, Atlanta.mdb, and with DataMaps10 US Streets locator.

I am trying to get my own MDB files to work.  I can do the following with them:

```
//Address -> Point 
//Address -> Closest Address Match 
//Point -> Nearest intersection 
//Intersection -> Point
```

**I can't get Point -> Address to work.**
I don't know how to identify the problem.  I project my IPoint coordinates to the projection of the MDB, but that doesn't work.  I've tried everything I can think of.  Can you give me some ideas of things to try to isolate the problem?   I have a temporary license for ArcMap for another week, so I can use that to help.  I'm using ArcEngine 10, C#, & VS 2010.

**Edit:**

I've uploaded a zip file here: http://www.filedropper.com/roads

It has an MDB, a shapefile and a projection.  I used the shapefile to create the MDB file.

I need to know how to reverse geocode this MDB file.  I need to just one more operation:

```
//Point -> Nearest Address
```

I would like to do it programmatically, but if you tell me the steps to do it in ArcMap, then I will have a decent idea how to implement it programatically, and that will be good enough.

To summarize:  How to use the MDB file as a locator to reverse geocode with ArcMap?

**Edit #2:** 
When I implement the sample here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001n9000000.htm

There is this line of code:

```
IPropertySet addressProperties = reverseGeocoding.ReverseGeocode(point, false /*return intersection */);
```

If the second parameter, return intersection == true, then it works.  But if the second parameter is equal to false, it throws a COM error,  0x80040217, which corresponds to 
GEOCODING_E_REVERSE_GEOCODE_NO_ADDRESS_FOUND .  I've tried a lot of different coordinates and I have my search radius equal to 1 km, so something should be found.

**Edit #3:**

I found this 
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=38314

Which points to this:  9.3.1 Locator Styles
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geocoding/details?entryID=12D8D400-1422-2418-34B0-4FE1CC06C0ED

I am hoping that I can get these 9.3.1 styles in the same way that the empirical programmer got it to work, and that might be a solution.  If I can I'll post it, and give you the points empirical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Kirk's locator and tried using the house icon, and clicking on the map.  I also don't get any addresses back ... don't really get why its not working in ArcMap 10.

So I exported the data out to a shape file then recreated a locator in 9.3.1 (US Streets style).

Then I opened the 9.3 locator up in ArcMap 10 with the original streets in the roads.mdb (from Kirk's download).  Now using the house icon, and clicking on the map seems to work.

Not really a long term answer but if you just need to get this working for the moment the locator files are at http://www.filedropper.com/loc93.

HTH

Comment: I downloaded the the 9.3.1 styles (link above) and added them to my locators directory according to the readme, then I set my style to US_Streets, and I could reverse geocode.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Arccatalog, I right clicked on your mdb and chose to create a new locator.  I then chose "US Address - dual ranges" for style and the roads featureclass as the reference data.  I zipped and uploaded the mdb [here](http://www.ambergis.com/roadswithlocator.zip).

I think you should now be able to use the code in this [reverse geocoding example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001n9000000.htm).

Comment: I opened ArcMap and set the "Default GeoDB for this map" to the file you uploaded.  Then I clicked Add Layer -> Streets, then I used the Geocode tool to change the address locator to "Streets_CreateAddressLocator", then I clicked the house icon, and then I clicked the map and nothing happened. I was expecting a little balloon popup with the nearest address.  I also tried programmatically to make it work, but it still failed.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I get the same thing.  Sorry don't have time to look into this.  I haven't tested reverse geocoding with 10.  Can you get the address inspector tool to work with one of the sample datasets?

Comment: I can get the address inspector to work with a file ESRI sent me called Atlanta.mdb.  So that leads me to the conclusion that some operation needs to be done to my MDB files in order to make them operational.  I don't know which sample datasets you mean.